# Jmeter 3.1 : Why sampler error not showing summary

Tags: jmeter

I am working on the JMeter 3.1 report module. I observed one problem while working on this. I have created four transaction controller and each transaction controller has some samples.

One of the sample is failing in one transaction controller. When I check the summary report it's showing 100% success status, Its not showing the errors.

Please find the attached screenshots with two type report. one report is showing errors and another one not showing error.

[image: Report generated using JMeter3.1]

================
[image: Report generated using ANT]

Please suggest, I am doing anything wrong or do I need to change any property values.

================